# How to use DarkSky API request with $.loadJSON?

Tags: javascript, weather-api

My weather app needs to use weather info, so I used DarkSky to give me that info. I decided to use jQuery's `$.loadJSON` to fetch weather data from the API. Why is the code below not working?

I've tried looking at the jQuery documentation but found no errors. I've swapped `$.loadJSON()` for `$.ajax()` and `$.get()`. I have tested that the longitude and latitude are correct. I've made sure there are no console errors.

```
let latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
let longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
let api = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[API Key]/${latitude},${longitude}`;

$.getJSON(api, (data, status, xhr) => {
    alert("API called.");

    let locationElement = document.querySelector("[data-location]");
    let statusElement = document.querySelector("[data-status]");
    let temperatureElement = document.querySelector("[data-temperature]");
    let humidityElement = document.querySelector("[data-humidity]");
    let windElement = document.querySelector("[data-wind]");

    locationElement.innerHTML = place.formatted_address;
    statusElement.innerHTML = data.currently.summary;
    temperatureElement.innerHTML = data.currently.temperature;
    humidityElement.innerHTML = data.currently.humidity;
    windElement.innerHTML = data.currently.windSpeed;
});
```

My expected result is that the code would edit all the labels on the page to the weather information. The actual result is that nothing happened. The labels stayed at their default state.

Comment: You can check if you are indeed building the correct URL by inserting it in the browser. If the URL is correct, you should see the weather forecast in the browser. What happens if you navigate to the URL you are building?

Comment: I checked the URL created by console logging it out and verified that it does give me the data I am looking for. When navigating to the link, my requested weather data show up. The problem is in the requesting function that fetches the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **should** get console errors. If you don't, then you might have an additional problem.

There is little point in trying to solve *that* though. As they explain in their FAQ, [they do not permit client-side cross-origin requests](https://darksky.net/dev/docs/faq#cross-origin) for security reasons.

> **Why do I get the error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource when I try to call the API? We take
>   security very seriously at Dark Sky. As a security precaution we have
>   disabled cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) on our servers.**
>
> Your API call includes your secret API key as part of the request. If
>   you were to make API calls from client-facing code, anyone could
>   extract and use your API key, which would result in a bill that you'd
>   have to pay. We disable CORS to help keep your API secret key a
>   secret.
>
> To prevent API key abuse, you should set up a proxy server to make
>   calls to our API behind the scenes. Then you can provide forecasts to
>   your clients without exposing your API key.